# Video Processing Issues

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, video-processing

I have some related question re: video processing on iOS.

1) Is it possible to pause, then resume, an AVVideoComposition processing session?  I ask this because I've run into problems merging large 1080p video files together when my app is running in the background (i.e., the 10-minute background processing limit for apps).   My experience so far has been that the video processing session fails if the app is in the background when the 10-minute limit is hit and the app gets stalled by iOS.  If I were able to pause the video processing session, I could detect the approach of the  10-minute limit, then pause the video processing until the user brings the app back to the forefront, then resume it, etc., etc.

2) In lieu of the above capability, is there a way to "extend" background processing for longer than 10 minutes?   My app does not fit under any of the categories of apps that are permitted to run continuously in the background.  But my need to do so for my app is legitimate and genuine - the reason being that  videos on the iphone are huge - 1080p with the newer iphones - and processing them takes a while.  In a way, it's not fair to users to limit an app's ability to process video taken on their behalf on the device the video was captured with.  Bottom line:  an app should be allowed to either continue it to it's completions, or pause and resume at a later time, as long as it's in  the middle of an AVComposition video processing session.

3) If neither of the above options is available, could you please recommend a strategy for dealing with this issue.  I want to make my app rock-solid in terms of reliability and letting the user know exactly what is going on.

4) Is it possible to up-convert a lower quality video to a higher (albeit fuzzier) quality?  For example:  say I want to merge two video clips, one a lower quality and one a higher quality.  Currently, if I merge these two together, the resulting video plays at the resolution of the higher-quality video;  the portion containing the lower-quality video plays in a smaller video frame in the upper-left corner of the larger video frame, with the rest of the frame blacked out.  What I'd prefer is to have the lower-quality video fill the larger frame, even if it gets fuzzy as a result. (NOTE:  I do want to maintain the aspect ratio of the lower quality video, however, so black bands across top/bottom or left/right are OK.)

Thanks!